# Why are my spells taking longer to cast as I level up?

Tags: world-of-warcraft

I have a Blood Elf Frost Mage that's level 19 and every time I level, my Frostbolt takes just a bit longer to cast. Right now, the normal cast time is about 2.1 seconds, and with a special ability it's about 1.5. Why is this?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Spell casting speeds are artificially lowered at low levels so you don't have to worry too much about advanced concepts like [spell pushback](http://www.wowpedia.org/Pushback) and to make the low-level game a bit more fast-paced.

The cast speed is scaled until around level 20, where you'll eventually hit the normal casting time for the spell.

For example, [Frostbolt's actual cast time](http://www.wowhead.com/spell=116) is 2 seconds: you reporting 2.1 seconds at level 19 indicates you're likely at or near the end of the scaling.

Additionally, if you have any items that have the [haste rating](http://www.wowpedia.org/Haste) attribute, one thing to keep in mind is that while haste lowers casting speeds, the amount of haste rating required to maintain the same speed reduction increases with level. So if you don't swap out your gear for things that have more haste rating, you'll find spell casting times increase as you gain levels.

Comment: This was a lot more obvious to see when you actually purchased new versions of spells and could see the old ones. This also had a nice advantage of casting quicker, lower damaging spells for situations like totems. Cataclysm changed this.

Comment: Cata didn't change this, WotLK did, when they made all of the spells cost the same, thusly removing wanting to cast lower damage/faster cast spells since there was no inherent mana saving reason to do it.